# Can there be a web application without cookies and JWT

Tags: cookies

Can a https:// web application with user login and password be developed without any system of
-cookies
-JWT
Will it be more more secure than using username/password as hidden field with every page?

Comment: vote to migrate to stackoverflow - this is a dev question. It might also be inappropriately scoped for their site, but it sure doesn't belong on this one

Comment: almost everything is *more secure than using username/password as hidden field with every page*

Comment: @JaromandaX yes. All people says so. But, -cookies -JWT are also transmitted/stored and can be stolen. Can somebody elaborate?

Comment: I answered the only question you asked - what more do you need?

Comment: @JaromandaX some explanation to support your answer.